# How to make ESXi 5.0 check datastore and get VMs automatically?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I've desktop pc dell 9010 with HD 500 GB (SATA )  , i'm working with ESXi 5.0 and i run it from flash memory ... I was created 4 guest VMs before but when i restart pc everytime it dosn't get Virtual machines (although the files of VMs on the hard disk but nothing in the invetory)   ... so i must create these machines again ... so i'm looking for solution to enforce ESXi to make scan on it's datastore and get these VMs again (something like commands or boot options)

Thank you everybody in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that's  the answer but i'm not sure [hosts inventory problem](http://terenceluk.blogspot.com/2011/12/esxi-41-hosts-inventory-no-longer-shows.html)